# Adding post matching filter in dropwizard

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

From the documentation of drop wizard it uses jersey's filters for filter configuration. Filters are called before the request reaches the registered resources. However, I want to decorate the response of that is being served from my resources. Is there a way to configure a post matching filter based on a url pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***First option***:

Yourclass implements ContainerRequestFilter if you want to filter out requests or modify them before they reach your Resources

and

Yourclass  implements ContainerResponseFilter if you want to filter out responses or modify them after they passed your Resources.

***Second option***:
You can use servlet filters -> http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#servlet-filters. If the page has changed when you view it, here the actual description:

```
public class DateNotSpecifiedServletFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    // Other methods in interface ommited for brevity

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            String dateHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader(HttpHeaders.DATE);

            if (dateHeader == null) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response); // This signals that the request should pass this filter
            } else {
                HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400);
                httpResponse.getWriter().print("Date Header was not specified");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your run():

```
environment.servlets().addFilter("DateHeaderServletFilter", new DateHeaderServletFilter())
                      .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
```

You can configure with true or false, if it is before or after. Hope this helps.

Comment: NB. This answer seems specific to Dropwizard >= 7.x. The syntax in DW <= 6.x to add a filter to your application is somewhat different, but the principle is the same.